# Recurring Donations

Tags: recurring-contributions, authorize.net

We have recurring donations every month. We have had several members increase their amounts that they want to donate. We use authorize.net and I changed the amounts and they have been charging the new amounts--but have not been showing up in the members record even though they were charged new amounts--
How do I Update a recurring donation so Authorize.net and CIVI CRM match?